# Killing a NodeJS Child Process with child.kill('SIGHUP')

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Here is my code:

**test.js**

```
const {exec} = require("child_process")

var c = exec("php artisan serve", {
        cwd: "C:/Users/DELL/Laravel Projects/lktest3"
    }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
})
setTimeout(() => {
    c.kill('SIGHUP')
}, 10000);
```

When I run `node test.js`, I get this error:

```
$ node test.js
internal/child_process.js:397
      throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
      ^

Error: kill ENOSYS
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:397:13)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\laravel-kit\test.js:14:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

I wrote this code as it is said in [NodeJS Child Process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal). But it's not working.

Comment: Are you using Windows? It doesn’t support sighup.

Comment: Try Killing with `SIGINT` signal or `c.kill()`

Comment: @nikita-isaev I am using Windows. So what can I do?

Comment: ```SIGINT``` and ```c.kill()``` both are not working.

Comment: @TarequeMdHanif use `c.kill('SIGINT');` instead

Comment: @NikitaIsaev It's not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [tree-kill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill) module to kill the child process on Windows.

Use it like this:

```
var kill = require('tree-kill');
kill(your_child_process.pid, 'SIGKILL', function(err) {
    // Do things
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `childProcess.spawn(command)` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)) instead of `childProcess.exec`, as “exec” creates a new shell and runs the command in that shell.